A user in ASP.NET MVC web application logged in as different user
I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC Framework 4.7.2 and IIS Express to run the application on my local machine. The web server that i am using is IIS 10. I am authenticating the user login using Keycloak through Docker. Docker Image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.1-legacy
I'm using https://github.com/mattmorg55/Owin.Security.Keycloak as an authentication middleware component.
The problem that i am facing is after login. I have noticed that in some cases, an user is logged in as a different user even though the user has provided the right login credentials. The problem occurs not that often, so i am not able to provide a reproducible example.
All Actions within the Controller has [Authorize] tag, which after session timeout forces the user to login page. I have used the ClaimsPrincipal to decode the access token provided by Keycloak to get the needed information.
using TestDashboard.DatabaseConnection;
using TestDashboard.IServices;
using TestDashboard.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestDashboard.Controllers.Special
{
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        //Called before the action method is called. Used for logging, caching, authorization
        [Authorize]
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
        {
            try
            {
                var userPrinciple = User as ClaimsPrincipal;

                if (Session["userDetails"] == null)
                {
                    //decode access token and set the required properties and store it to a 'userDetails' session
                    UserDetailsModel userDetailsModel = new UserDetailsModel().DecodeAccessToken(userPrinciple);

                    if (userDetailsModel.exceptionMessageModel.statusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    {
                        ThrowErrorPage("/Error/Forbidden");
                    }
                    else if (userDetailsModel.exceptionMessageModel.statusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                    {
                        ThrowErrorPage("/Error/InternalError");
                    }
                    else if (userDetailsModel.exceptionMessageModel.statusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                    {
                        ThrowErrorPage("/Error/BadRequest");
                    }
                    else if (userDetailsModel.exceptionMessageModel.statusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        ThrowErrorPage("/Error/Pagenotfound");
                    }

                    Session["userDetails"] = userDetailsModel;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log execption to elasticsearch
                new ElasticsearchConnection().IndexExceptionDocument(e, GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" Exception in Class Name-> " + GetType().Name + ", Method Name-> " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ", Error-> " + e.Message);

                ThrowErrorPage("/Error/InternalError");
            }
        }
        public ActionResult ThrowErrorPage(string pathToError)
        {
            return Redirect(pathToError);
        }
    }
}

Has anybody faced the same issue or something similar?
